# why I can't set the same height and width by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wish to build a sketchpad by using jQuery to dynamically set width and height for each div grid.

However the result shows a different size of height and width. From the JQuery code, I understand that I have successfully created 16*16 div blocks. I then assign it with height and width by using `selector.css(width:function(){})`.

As a result, I am expecting to see a 16 * 16 grid of blocks with the same size. However, it displays different sizes of blocks. I have no clue why this happens, can anyone enlighten me?

```js
var input = 16;


$(document).ready(function(){

 
    for(var i = 0; i<input*input;i++){
 $('.wrapper').append("<div></div>");
   }

 $('.wrapper').find('div').css({
    width: function(input) {
      return 200/input;
    },
    height: function(input) {
     return 200/input;
    }
  });
 $('.wrapper').find('div').addClass('grid');
 $('.wrapper').find('div').on('mouseenter',function(){
 $(this).addClass('highlight');

});

});
```

```css
.wrapper{
 width: 900px;
 height: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;

}

.grid{
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 2px 2px;
}

.highlight{
 background-color: blue;

}

#button{
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

button{
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
}

body{
 background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src = "sketchpad.js"></script>



 <div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $('.wrapper').find('div').width(200/input);
  $('.wrapper').find('div').height(200/input);

  /*$('.wrapper').find('div').css({
    width: function(input) {
      return 200/input;
    },
    height: function(input) {
     return 200/input;
    }
  });*/
```

reomve commented code section and add above code section.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.wrapper').find('div').css({
    width: function(input) {
      return 200/input;
    },
    height: function(input) {
     return 200/input;
    }
  });
```

I think you just forgot to put width and height unit.

```
$('.wrapper').find('div').css({
        width: function(input) {
          return 200/input + 'px';
        },
        height: function(input) {
         return 200/input + 'px';
        }
      });
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `width` function you specified:

```
width: function(input) { return 200/input; },
```

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width-function) this function:

> Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old
>   width as arguments.

Thus the parameter `input` contains the index position of div, e.g. `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. That is why you see blocks which are invisible (position `0`), have a height/width of `200` (position `1`), etc.

The solution is to use a variable instead of a function to set the width:

```
var block_width = 200 / input; 

$('.wrapper').find('div').css({
    width: block_width,
    height: block_width
});
```